# How to run AWS sample JAVA code on an EC2

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I just started with Amazon web services, and I have an EC2 instance. I downloaded the JAVA SDK and the Eclipse toolbox. I am able to run a sample program locally on my PC and connect to the Amazon databases, etc. My question is, what do I need to do to get this working on my EC2 instance? This may not even be specific to AWS. On Eclipse, I can just "Run as Application" and run any code. On the server side, what do I need to do? Should I ftp over my .java files? Should I export it to a jar and upload that? Do I need to install anything special to actually run it?

I'm just trying to run the basic DynamoDB example that connects to the database and adds a new table and row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to upload your .class (or .jar) to your EC2 and run it there.

If you are not limited to that particular instance of EC2 you can use [Amazon Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) which let's say a tomcat container to run your code. That way you can deploy the "app" from Eclipse.

Comment: How can I deploy to Beanstalk from Eclipse?  Is there some way I can use the Eclipse plugin to upload code to my Beanstalk?

Will Beanstalk automatically create EC2 instances with everything I need?

Comment: if you want to just run a "java.exe" with your jar then no. But if you can wrap it as a Java Web Application Archive (war) then you can use beanstalk to upload it, run the ec2 with everything you need